# Matching colors in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How would I match this color exactly in my code? http://www.color-hex.com/color/ccccff

My code-

```
public static Color backColor = new Color(193f, 104f, 155f, 255f);
```

No matter what I do it will not match the back color like i'm trying to make it do. Keep in mind I am very new to this, and almost finished with my project. Thanks. It is for an android app.

Comment: And what `Color` class is this (since it is neither `java.awt.Color` or `android.graphics.Color`)? And I really don't understand why you're not using the color code from the site you've posted ...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
Color.parseColor("#ccccff");
```

which will return the int color.

Comment: How would that look in the code? It doesn't recognize "parseColor"

Comment: For instance you would write mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(...)); in order to set the back color of a WebView